# Unmarshal JSON from Wikipedia API

Tags: go

I need to get a JSON from the Wikipedia API in GoLang using this URL https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts|pageimages&exintro&explaintext&generator=search&gsrsearch=intitle:wikipedia&gsrlimit=1&redirects=1

The code below works but If I change the search key (from Wikipedia to any thing else), it no longer works because of `json:"5043734"`. I was told to use `Pages map[string]*struct` instead and I made modifications in my code.

My code:

```
type Wiki struct {
        Batchcomplete string `json:"batchcomplete"`
        Continue      struct {
            Gsroffset int    `json:"gsroffset"`
            Continue  string `json:"continue"`
        } `json:"continue"`
        Query struct {
            Pages map[string]*struct {

                    Pageid    int    `json:"pageid"`
                    Ns        int    `json:"ns"`
                    Title     string `json:"title"`
                    Index     int    `json:"index"`
                    Extract   string `json:"extract"`
                    Thumbnail struct {
                        Source string `json:"source"`
                        Width  int    `json:"width"`
                        Height int    `json:"height"`
                    } `json:"thumbnail"`
                    Pageimage string `json:"pageimage"`

            } `json:"pages"`
        } `json:"query"`

    }

    wikipedia:="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts|pageimages&exintro&explaintext&generator=search&gsrsearch=intitle:wikipedia&gsrlimit=1&redirects=1"
      res, err := http.Get(wikipedia)

      if err != nil {
           panic(err.Error())
         }

        body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)

        if err != nil {
             panic(err.Error())
           }

          var data Wiki

          // unmarshall
          json.Unmarshal(body, &data)
          //fmt.Printf("Results: %v\n", data)

          // print values of the object
          fmt.Printf("Title: " + data.Query.Pages.Title)      
          fmt.Printf("Extract: "+ data.Query.Pages.Extract)
```

I need to make modifications according to the given example but I don't know how to do it in my case. I have tried but no success.

The result I get with my old code:
[image]

But if I change `srsearch=intitle:wikipedia` in my URL to `srsearch=intitle:Planet+Mars` it no longer works because of the ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Pages` is a map.  You can range through the map to find the pages:

```
for pageID, page := range data.Query.Pages {
    fmt.Println(pageID, page.Title, page.Extract)
}
```

Comment: Thank you It's working but could tell me how I achieve a similar result like the screenshot I posted? Because now I get this too `5043734 &{5043734 0 Wikipedia 1 Wikipedia ( (listen)`I would like to separately get the Title value and the Extract value.

Comment: I edited the answer to show how to access the title and extract fields.

Comment: Thank you very much. It might be basic but 'm a complete beginner in Golang.

Comment: @ThiagoGuimarães  Take the Tour of Go.  https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/19

Answer (score -1):

To get those data easily, use this module: [github.com/trietmn/go-wiki](https://github.com/trietmn/go-wiki)

Example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/trietmn/go-wiki"
)

// Getting the Wikipedia page "Rafael Nadal"
func main() {
    // Get the page
    page, err := gowiki.GetPage("Rafael Nadal", -1, false, true)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    // Get the content of the page
    content, err := page.GetContent()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Page title: %v\n", page.Title)
    fmt.Printf("Page ID: %v\n", page.PageID)
    fmt.Printf("Page content (Extract): %v\n", content)
}
```

You can get the title, pageid, content of a page with only a few lines of code. Here's the tutorial [Golang Wikipedia module tutorial](https://dev.to/trietmn/golang-wikipedia-module-33db)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: + Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.